# Extract content from url and website

Tags: php, jquery, class, wrapper

I get content from website using `file_get_contents()`.

When I get this content I can see all the content and tags of the website.

I need to extract the content from some of the tags, not all of them. I think the best it´s get the content and save it into a database or a text file for future manipulation.

For example if I get this with php `file_get_contents()`:

```
<html>
    <head><script src="script.js"></head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>

        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>

        <div id="image"></div>

        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>

        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get for example only the content of divs with the class `item`? Is it possible to use jQuery or do I need to use php? I have tried many things but I need a guide or someone to tell me how I can extract what I need

Thanks, Regards

Comment: Tried many things ?? Show us one please.

Comment: No expert in wrapper i try explode content but no the best way

Comment: I think the best would be to read up on PHP's [**DOMDocument**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and parse the returned markup with that.

Comment: **Learn** the `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`. Or `Regular Expressions` for basic uses.

Comment: `DOMDocument`, as above: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to parse HTML and extract only the data you want to is to render it using a popular framework like WebKit.

Try using PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) which is a program that will let you render a webpage (via command line) and interact with it using javascript or APIs.

I'd just save the file, load it into PhantomJS, with my own jquery $('body').('.item').each(....

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need [**`cURL`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for scraping. `file_get_contents()` = poor man's scraping with no custom headers, fake referrer and such.
2. What was scraped has to be loaded into a [**`DOMDocument`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
3. You need to use [**`DOMXPath`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to locate the nodes you need easily in the DOM tree.
4. As a backup plan, if parsing is easy `preg_match_all()` might to the trick if handled with care.

You got a plan... **GO STUDY** and learn how to do it!